# Laravel CRUD API - in update method if I send a Model I have only model with out ID or other information

Tags: php, laravel, crud

Laravel CRUD API - in update method if I send a Model I have only model with out ID or other information
My expamle is :

```
 public function update(GoogleIndexingUpdate $request, GoogleIndexing $page)
{
        dd($page);
}
```

GoogleIndexingUpdate is Request
GoogleIndexing is Model
dd($page) - return model, no current model
But if I used with out model I have ID

```
 public function update(GoogleIndexingUpdate $request, $page)
{
        dd($page);
}
```

dd($page) is 1

Ho can I use Model in method query to have straightaway current model ?

Return current model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are successfully obtaining the ID after removing the Model Name from the function arguments, then this is related to your route binding.

Double check your route, for example if your route is something like this -
`https://example.com/api/indexing/{page}`
then only in controller you can access the model directly, it's called [**Implicit Binding**](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-binding).

In case you don't want to change the route, rather change the **Binding Key**, you can change the variable name on controller like this -

```
public function update(GoogleIndexingUpdate $request, GoogleIndexing $yourroutevariable)
{
    dd($yourroutevariable);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the route is the same for your example PUT|PATCH | api/google/indexing/resource/{resource}. And I use it in routing Route::apiResource('google/indexing/resource', 'GoogleIndexingController'); . I read more about Implicit Binding in resource API

Comment: @Sviat In your route you are using {resource} but in the controller you are using `public function update(GoogleIndexingUpdate $request, GoogleIndexing $page)` change it to `public function update(GoogleIndexingUpdate $request, GoogleIndexing $resource)` that will work.